# doing an array_push to an array inside an array

Tags: php

```
$mainstack = array(
            'applet' => "Flow"
        );

    $menustack = array(
        'applet' => "Menu",
        'repeat' => "2"
        );

    $dialstack = array(

        );

    $dial1 = array(
        'applet' => "Dial",
        'number' => "165465468",
        'whisper' => "Yes",
        );
    $dial2 = array(
        'applet' => "Dial",
        'number' => "654984",
        'whisper' => "No",
        );
    $dial3 = array(
        'applet' => "Dial",
        'number' => "398965165",
        'whisper' => "Yes",
        );

    array_push($mainstack, $menustack);
    array_push($dialstack, $dial1);
    array_push($dialstack, $dial2);
    array_push($dialstack, $dial3);
    array_push($menustack, $dialstack);
```

Is there a way where I can insert `$dialstack` inside of `$menustack` after putting `menustack` inside of `$mainstack`? The outcome I want is possible by moving `array_push($mainstack, $menustack);` to the last line, but I am really looking for a way where I can just insert an array to an existing stack of arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to know the index of $menustack inside of $mainstack

```
$arrayOne = [];
$arrayTwo = [];
$arrayThree = [];

// $arrayOne goes inside of $arrayTwo
array_push($arrayTwo, $arrayOne);

// $arrayThree goes inside of $arrayTwo[0] which is $arrayOne
array_push($arrayTwo[0], $arrayThree);

var_dump($arrayTwo);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_push($mainstack,array_merge($menustack,$dialstack));
print_r($mainstack);
```

First merge two arrays using [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) then push them in `$mainstack`